# Cómo poner en otras listas elementos de otras listas según una lógica en python

Tags: python

quiera pedir ayuda sobre cómo puedo poner elementos de una lista en otra lista según un orden especifico, es decir el primer elemento en la primera lista, el segundo en la segunda lista, el tercero en la tercer lista, el cuarto vuelve a estar en la primera, el quinto en la segunda y así sucesivamente.

Gracias

Comment: Mejor agrega un ejemplo de que quieres hacer: listas de entrada y la lista de salida deseada. También agrega el código que llevas escrito hasta el momento.

Answer (score 2):

Partimos de la siguiente idea:

- El operador *slice* (rodaja) permite tomar los elementos de una lista de N en N. En tu caso de 3 en 3. Por ejemplo `lista[0::3]` toma todos los elementos de la lista, partiendo del que tiene índice 0 hasta el final, pero sumando 3 a cada índice. Así que extrae los elementos de índices 0, 3, 6, 9 ... Estos son justamente los que necesitas para la primera lista
- Si cambiamos el índice de inicio, así: `lista[1::3]`, extraerá ahora los de índice 1, 4, 7, 10, ... Y estos son los que necesitas para la segunda lista.
- Finalmente con `lista[2::3]` comenzaría por el índice 2, extrayendo los de índices 2,5, 8, 11, ... que son tu tercera lista.

Así pues:

```
lista_1 = lista[0::3]
lista_2 = lista[1::3]
lista_3 = lista[2::3]
```

Esto lo podemos abreviar a una línea si usamos la asignación múltiple (una tupla con tres elementos a cada lado del signo `=`):

```
lista_1, lista_2, lista_3 = lista[0::3], lista[1::3], lista[2::3]
```

Veamos si funciona con una lista de ejemplo de 20 elementos:

```
lista = list(range(20))
lista_1, lista_2, lista_3 = lista[0::3], lista[1::3], lista[2::3]
```

Resultado:

```
lista_1: [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
lista_2: [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19] 
lista_3: [2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17]
```

### Generalización

Podemos hacer una función que reciba la lista que hay que separar, y el número de sublistas. Ese número coincide no sólo con el número de sublistas a generar, sino también con el paso que hay que usar en el *slice*, así que la función queda simplemente así:

```
def separar(lista, n):
  return [lista[i::n] for i in range(n)]
```

Demo de funcionamiento:

```
>>> separar(lista, 3)
[[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18], 
 [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19], 
 [2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17]]

>>> separar(lista, 6)
[[0, 6, 12, 18],
 [1, 7, 13, 19],
 [2, 8, 14],
 [3, 9, 15],
 [4, 10, 16],
 [5, 11, 17]]
```

Comment: Te agradezco mucho. Me sirvió bastante.